# MS Test & private accessors: get access to private nested class

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

I'm using MS Test in combination with private accessors to unit test my classes. I make a great usage of private accessors (not available in VS 2012 :-( ) to invoke my private methods. That works fine.

But I am not able to access private nested classes!

For example:

```
public class Tool
{
  private IList<Result> DoSomePreparation(object anything)
  {
    // do some preparations here
  }

  private class Result { }
}
```

By means of a private accessor a can access my private method

```
{
  var accessor = new Tool_Accessor(new PrivateObject(new Tool()));
  accessor.DoSomePreparation(new object());
}
```

But how can I access the nested class? 
I need it since I would like to mock the result coming from DoSomePreparation(...).

Comment: What method DoSomePreparation actually do? Because when it's some preparation, e.g. properties initialization - it could be used from property initializer syntax outside class. Or when it reads something from XML, read logic could be separated from class. Here is some mix of responsibility. Such logic could be implemented outside of it, and then its public contract could be tested too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tool_Accessor.Result - would be your accessor to nested class.

Answer (score 1):

Most common way in such cases is to test public contract of class, and avoid testing privates, because it makes tests more fragile to changes in actual implementation. Try to design your API avoiding to test private methods. When testing of private methods needed, then in such cases classes can break single responsibility principle.

As example, XML serialization. When XML serialization is made inside a class that represents domain business object, especially with inheritance, when there hierarchy between domain objects. In such case it would be hard to test such domain object with XML serialization implementation inside. But when implement XML serialization outside domain object, than both domain object and object with XML serialization logic could be easily tested using public contract.

Sometimes it's hard to avoid testing of private methods. In context of .NET you can make such methods accessible as internals, and access to it from tests using [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute.

Comment: In general I agree, but as you say in some cases you need to test the private methods.